# XPATH Search Next Node

Tags: c#, xpath

I need to select the parent node of my XPATH.

**XML**

```
<PatientDetailsXML>             
 <PList> 
               <PName type="Patient">
            <properties>
                <Room bedType="Auto" />
                <PName title="Joe Beom" PId="1234">
                    <Details>
                        <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Wallet" />
                        <classification classification="Humor" category="None" />
                        <classification classification="Food" category="Fruit" />
                    </Details>
                </PName>
                </properties>
            <childEvents>
            </childEvents>
        </PName>
                <PName type="Patient">
            <properties>
                <Room bedType="Auto" />
                <PName title="John Bair" PId="1234">
                    <Details>
                        <classification classification="paymenttype" category="Found" />
                        <classification classification="Humor" category="None" />
                        <classification classification="Food" category="Vegetables" />
                    </Details>
                </PName>
                </properties>
            <childEvents>
            </childEvents>
        </PName>
</PList>
</PatientDetailsXML>
```

If my `currentnode` is `<PName type="Patient">`, 1st one in the list above. I need to search the next node with `<classification classification="Food" category="Vegetables" />` and select it's Title in  `<PNAME title>`.

**CODE**

```
var testing = nodes[i].SelectSingleNode(@"following::Details/classification[@classification='Food'and @category ='Vegetables']")ParentNode.ParentNode.Attributes["title"].Value;
```

If you see above I'm doing a `.ParentNode.ParentNode` to reach `<PNAME title>`. This is working fine for me. But is there a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required attribute

```
"following::Details/classification[@classification='Food'and @category ='Vegetables']/ancestor::PNAME/@title"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
1. "ancestor" - which selects all parents and grandparents of the current node 
2. "ancestor-or-self" - which selects all parents and grandparents of the current node including node itself.